# Dashboard for MOBILE BROADBANDS

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 3g, broadband

Is there any dashboard for mobile broadband in UBUNTU 13.04?

Like this

[image]
[image]

Comment: Depends on the broadband provider. The last two dongles I've purchased have come with Linux software on board which look very much like your first screenshot.

Comment: What sort of functionality would you expect from such an application?

Comment: Looks like text messaging and calling... I had found an app to do this at one point but don't remember the name nor did I ever get it to actually work.

Comment: There is definitely a need for this app., for Ubuntu-Touch. *Please start coding, or create set of screen shots, menu, features, ..*

Answer (score 0):

[Wammu](https://wammu.eu/screenshots/?page=1) comes closest, as far as I know, the feature to make phone-calls hasn't been implemented. The [feature list](https://wammu.eu/wammu/) includes:

- Complete support (can read/edit/delete/copy) for contacts, todo, calendar
- Can read/create/save/send/backup SMSes
- Sending files to phone (OBEX and Sony Ericsson phones only)
- SMS composer for multi part SMes (currently only text and predefined bitmap/sound can be edited)
- Display message including pictures and ringtones playback
- Support for backup and import in various formats (vCard, vCalendar, vTodo, iCalendar, gammu own backup,...)
- Export messages to mail (IMAP4, maildir and mailbox storages are supported)
- Searching for phone
- Translated into several languages
- rated as best on many software servers

[image: Screenshot of Wammu]